# I want to cook brown and white rice together

Tags: rice

I want to cook brown rice and jasmine rice in the same pot, or normal white rice whatever works better with brown rice. Is it possible to do so without having mushy white rice. I love brown rice i want to mix it up

Comment: Do they need to be *cooked* together, rather than just cooking them separately and mixing before serving?

Comment: If your main goal is mixing it up, I find grains like millet and farro have similar cooking times to brown rice

Comment: I haven’t done it myself, but I was watching an episode of Simply Ming, and he mentioned that he does half and half, but soaks the brown rice in water before mixing it with the white rice in his rice cooker.  I have no idea how much water to add, though.

Answer (score 23):

That is possible, but you need to stage the cooking process. If your preferred cooking method for brown rice takes X minutes and for white Y minutes, start cooking the brown rice as usual,  and add the white rice after X-Y minutes.

For example (and those numbers may vary depending on your rice and preferences):
Brown rice needs 40 minutes, the jasmine needs 18 minutes. Then add the jasmine after 22 (40-18) minutes.

If you usually cook the rice at low-low heat, you may have to crank up the heat for a short while to bring the pot back to a boil after adding the white rice.

If you cook by the absorption method, you can add the whole amount of water at the beginning (for both kinds) and perhaps add a tablespoon or two to compensate for the loss when you open the pot to add the second batch of rice.

Answer (score -6):

Try adding more water, that always helps.